# Combine multiple queries into one active record relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to write a search query for my app where based on the query string it will search for groups or users matching the string.

Here is what I have written:

```
    def search_api
      @groups = Group.where("name ILIKE '#{params[:query]}'")
      @users = User.where("first_name ILIKE '#{params[:query]}' OR last_name ILIKE '#{params[:query]}")
    end
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries into one activerecord relation array? Besides the brute force iterating over both arrays and putting them into one?

Comment: You will not be able to create one query that combines both of these results, unless groups and users are based in the same table through single table inheritance. This is because they'll be in two different tables and ActiveRecord only lets you hit one table at once (unless you're writing your own SQL with unions but that's taking you away from your AR results anyway, and you can't join your way to this)

Comment: @SharvyAhmed PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name ILIKE :query UNION SELECT * ...

Answer (score 2):

*I am not sure about the solution but I have a security suggestion.*

Your queries are not SQL Injection safe. You could pass array instead of injecting params in SQL string.

The following queries are SQL injection safe:

```
@groups = Group.where("name ILIKE ?", "#{params[:query]}")
@users = User.where("first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ?", "#{params[:query]}")
```

Comment: Thanks I'll do that. Out curiosity how does this make it safer?

Comment: Here is quick reference for you to follow - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html (section 7). When you pass array instead of prepared SQL statement, activerecord sanitizes the parameters before query. But when you pass statement, it will be used as it is, without any kind of sanitization.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name ILIKE :query UNION SELECT * ...

Comment: `Group.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name ILIKE ? UNION SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ?", "#{params[:query]}")` could you try this?

Comment: Doesn't like that one either. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"`

Comment: Group.find_by_sql("(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name ILIKE ?) UNION (SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ?)", "#{params[:query]}")

Comment: @IvanSelivanov, are you sure? Have you tried? I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

So here is a solution. Not sure that it is better than leaving everything as it is, but formally it's the answer to a question (besides that the result is not an ActiveRecord relation):

```
 Group.connection.execute("(SELECT id, 'groups' as table FROM groups WHERE...) UNION (SELECT id, 'users' as table FROM users WHERE...)")
```

This returns an object of type `PG::Result` which you can treat as array of hashes. And, as it has already been said, it is good to pass arguments as an array instead of inserting them directly into SQL. Unfortunately, if You want to get a result as ActiveRecord, you may use `UNION` only for different queries to one table. In that case it looks like:

```
 Group.find_by_sql("(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE...) UNION (SELECT * FROM groups WHERE...)")
```